# Heaviside step function properties $\theta(t-t_1) \theta(t_1-t_2) + \theta(t-t_2) \theta(t_2-t_1) = \theta(t-t_1) \theta(t-t_2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, dirac-delta

I want to prove the following Heaviside theta function property :

\begin{align}
\theta(t-t_1) \theta(t_1-t_2) + \theta(t-t_2) \theta(t_2-t_1) = \theta(t-t_1) \theta(t-t_2)
\end{align}

Recalling the definitions of theta
\begin{align}
\theta(x) = \begin{cases}
1 , x\geq 0\\
0, x<0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
In some sense, i got the feeling but I want to show this property with explicitly.

Comment: Assuming some order relation between $t,t_1,t_2$ allows you to compute all quantities in the expression. Just consider all possible relations between these numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $t=t_1=t_2$. Then your relation becomes $2=1$ which is false.

Assume now that $t_1\neq t_2$. More precisely $t_1<t_2$ (the other case is treated the same way). The right hand side is non zero if and only if $t\geq t_1$ and $t\geq t_2$.

Then the left hand side becomes
$$\theta(t-t_2)\theta(t_2-t_1)=\theta(t-t_2)$$
which is alzo non-zero if and only if $t \geq t_2>t_1$.